# Session is not working in controller when I call from unitTesting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have ASP.NET MVC project. Now I am learning how to use UnitTesting. For this purpose I created UnitTest project.

I have below code in my Testclass :

```c#
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {         
        Controller defaultpage = new Controller();

        var result = defaultpage.defaultpage("43", "Y", "Y");
    }
}

public ActionResult defaultpage(string uid, string access, string add)
    {
        Session["uid"] = uid;
        Session["access"] = access;
        Session["add"] = add;
    }
```

Here when it comes to defaultpage controller method, it is giving **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** .

How do I take session in controller when i call from UnitTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock session since it's not defined in the context of a unit test;

Here is a brief summary of how to mock session using c# and MOQ

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-mock-httpcontext

The basics of it can be summed up with this block:

```
Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
session.Setup(s => s["SomeSessionKey"]).Returns(someObject);
httpContext.Setup(c => c.Session).Returns(session.Object);
```

Another alternative is to use NSubstitute which is a library with an api very similar to MOQ

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your controller is working independent of the HTTP Context and HTTP pipeline that exists when visiting your ASP.NET MVC application in a hosted environment running IIS.

In this instance you'll need to look at mocking your session using a library such as [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

Then you're able to create a mocked implementation of the HTTP context object which contains the session like so (code sample taken from [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/724300/Mocking-Session-State-in-an-ASP-NET-MVC-Unit-Test) that I would recommend you take a look at):

```
// create the mock http context
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock();

// create a mock session object and hook it up to the mock http context
var sessionMock = new HttpSessionMock {{"selectedYear", 2013}, {"selectedMonth", 10}};
var mockSessionState = new Mock();
fakeHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(sessionMock);

// ... and here's how to attach a http context identity, just in case you'll come to need that,     too
var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("mno@ucsj.dk");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);
fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal);

// we'll need to hook our http context up to a controller context mock - because we can't provide     our controller with the http context mock directly
var homeControllerMock = new Mock();
homeControllerMock.Setup(foo => foo.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);
```